# MySQL views, database name prefixes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

Mysql 8.X

Database name: db1.

In this database, I create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw1 AS
SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

When I check the source code of the view, instead of the code above, I can see:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.sometable;
```

I.e. MySQL engine automatically adds a database name prefix to every table I refer to in the view.

Now, I need to rename my database from db1 to db2. There is no built-in database rename functionality in MySQL. I have to take a backup, then drop the original database, then restore the backup under a new name.

Result: the vw1 view in my new db2 database tries to select rows from (now non-existing) db1 database, causing errors.

Now imagine 100s of databases, with 100s or 1000s of tables each. This issue makes things absolutely non-manageable.

Is there *any* way of stopping MySQL from adding database prefixes in view definitions?

Comment: Note that queries against views in mysql cannot access underlying indexes, so I'd question their usefulness, altogether.

Comment: No. When the view is used the current database is indefinite in general (i.e. it can be changed at any time) - so view source MUST be fully qualified. If you use a view as final (retrieved by client) rowset then use stored procedure instead.

Comment: Other DB engines assume that a table with no prefix belongs to the same database as the view itself. This works perfectly well in the backup / restore scenario. I don't understand why MySQL insists on prefixing everything.